# How would I say “monthly deduction” in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, économie

I saw “déduction mensuelle” in Google Translate, but I wasn't sure that that's accurate.  I think I want *prélèvements* don't I?

It's a header in a document. There will be a monthly deduction option for employees who want to purchase something. So instead of dropping a lump sum, they can opt for a monthly deduction.

Comment: Could you give more information about the context and the expected meaning? Without more information, _prélèvements_ is probably not the word needed and _déduction_ seems good but _réduction_ could be better.

Comment: There isn't much of a context.  It's for a header in a document.  There will be a monthly deduction option for employees who want to purchase something.  So instead of dropping a lump sum, they can opt for a monthly deduction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In that context, *prélèvements mensuels* is indeed more idiomatic.